# How do I publish a project that uses WatIn?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, exe, watin, publish

I have a project that makes use of WatIn. I have in the past been able to go into the Debug folder and just run the .exe to make use of the program, however trying that with this program throws errors related to WatIn. Since WatIn is not part of the .Net framework installation, is there a way to run the program by itself without loading the entire project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Posting the error messages would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not already there, maybe you need the WatiN dll's in the folder?

Comment: I copied all files included in the Bin>Debug folder along with the .exe and put it in one folder. Can run it from that folder now. Thanks for the recommend.